# Unsuccessful attempt using "google-code-prettify" with dynamically DOM

Tags: jquery, html, prettify, google-code-prettify

Inside `head` tag I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="google-code-prettify/prettify.css">
<script src="google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
```

Somewhere inside body tag I have:

```
<div id='code-context'>
    <pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-js"></code></pre>
</div>
```

In my main css file I have some `pre` and `code` which should override prettify:

```
#code-context pre, #code-context code {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
    width: 80ch;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Intentionally**, I didn't include `<body onload="prettyPrint()">`.
The `#code-context` is hidden when the page is loaded so it's unnecessary. The code become visible after the user trigger a jQuery function which goes:

```
$('#code-context').show();
var fileSource = "code-to-display.js";
$('code').load(fileSource);
$('.prettyprinted').removeClass('prettyprinted');
prettyPrint();
console.log('succeded!');
```

I'm getting the message in the console (which implies that all went OK), but in fact what I get is a border around all the code, and the code itself isn't color-coded.

Help?

Comment: is the CSS file being loaded?

Comment: @gabe3886, I added information to the question, would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I used jQuery's `get()` instead of `load()` and it worked, though I don't fully understand why.